# Unix: Turn multiple line file into single line

Tags: unix

What is the simplest command to convert a multi-line file into a single line file in Unix?

Sample data in the file is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1
   JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
   WHERE t1.ID = 123
```

Desired output is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID) WHERE t1.ID = 123
```

I have tried using :

```
/bin/sed '{:q;N;s/  / /g;s/\n//g;t q}' $1
```

But it is not successful. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sed` like this:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n\s*/ /g' file
```

Or using `awk` like this:

```
awk '{ $1 = $1 }1' RS= file
```

Results:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID) WHERE t1.ID = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to update an sql stored in unix directory.
If you have Notepad++ installed, you can just replace **\r\n** with either a space or an empty string. Be sure to select "**Extended**" in the search mode

Answer (score 1):

With Perl:

```
perl -p -e'chomp' filename
```

Addendum:

If it's important to have a trailing newline and for leading whitespace to get removed from each line, you could do this:

```
perl -l -n -e's/^\s+//; push @x, $_; END { print join( ' ', @x ); }' filename
```

Comment: You may as well use `tr -d "\n" < file` as neither of these solutions will remove any leading whitespace. These solutions also remove the last newline character in the file, which could have downstream consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (depending on the definition of "simple") is:

```
tr -s \\n ' '
```

If you want the output to have a newline:

```
 { tr -s \\n \ < input-file && echo; } > output-file
```